# Python/Numpy subarray selection

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some Numpy code which I'm trying to decipher. There's a line `v1 = v1[:, a1.tolist()]` which passes a numpy array `a1` and converts it into a list. I'm confused as to what `v1[:, a1.tolist()]` actually does. I know that `v1` is now being set to a column array given from `v1` given by the selection `[:, a1.tolist()]` but what's getting selected? More precisely, what is `[:, a.tolist()]` doing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax you observed is easier to understand if you split it in two parts:

### 1. Using a list as index

With numpy the meaning of

```
a[[1,2,3]]
```

is

```
[a[1], a[2], a[3]]
```

In other words when using a list as index is like creating a list of using elements as index.

### 2. Selecting a column with `[:,x]`

The meaning of

```
a2[:, x]
```

is

```
[a2[0][x],
 a2[1][x],
 a2[2][x],
 ...
 a2[n-1][x]]
```

I.e. is selecting one column from a matrix.

### Summing up

The meaning of

```
a[:, [1, 3, 5]]
```

is therefore

```
[[a[ 0 ][1], a[ 0 ][3], a[ 0 ][5]],
 [a[ 1 ][1], a[ 1 ][3], a[ 1 ][5]],
               ...
 [a[n-1][1], a[n-1][3], a[n-1][5]]]
```

In other words a copy of `a` with a selection of columns (or duplication and reordering; elements in the list of indexes doesn't need to be distinct or sorted).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a simple example like a 2D array, `v1[:, a1.tolist()]` would selects all rows of `v1`, but only columns described by `a1` values

Simple example:

```
>>> x
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'f', 'g']],
      dtype='|S1')

>>> x[:,[0]]
array([['a'],
       ['d']],
      dtype='|S1')
>>> x[:,[0, 1]]
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['d', 'f']],
      dtype='|S1')
```